# Auto-format a *.vm file as HTML

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

In VSCode, how can we auto-format the HTML in a `.vm`(not `.html`) file?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the language mode for any file. Open your `*.vm` file in vscode. Then do this:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Type `Change language mode`.
3. Choose `HTML.

[image]

Now when you you format the document, the formatting will be for HTML.